# How to change visibility of menu on click

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I am working on an HTML template and I have some trouble with my menu. 
Please find the direct link to the template here : onepage-test.surge.sh.

The goal is this one : On big screens, the menu is fully visible with inline links. Here comes the issue : on devices with a width inferior to 780px, I want the menu to become a burger-menu. I used Fontawesome's fa-bars icon. By default, only the three bars are visible. What I would like is for the menu to open when clicking the three bars.

I tried both vanilla js and jQuery solutions but none worked for me.

Here is my HTML :

```
<i onclick="open();" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
<menu id="menu">
    <li><a href="#whatwedo">What we do</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
</menu>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
#menu{
    position:fixed;
    visibility:visible;

    @media screen and (max-width:780px){
        visibility:hidden;
    }
}
```

And here is my JS :

```
function open() {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    if (menu.style.visibility == "visible"){
        menu.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }if (menu.style.visibility == "hidden"){
        menu.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

I expect the menu to open at the time I click on the bars. What currently happen is a blank page that shows up.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: toggle a class, so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is open() refers to window.open()

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i onclick="console.log(open);" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

Change your method name and just toggle a class

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
#menu {
  display: none;
}

#menu.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<i onclick="toggleMenu();" class="fa fa-bars"></i>
<menu id="menu">
  <li><a href="#whatwedo">What we do</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see problems with this line:

```
<i onclick="open();" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
```

The `i` tag is for making font [italic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i). I'm not sure you can put a click event on that tag.

Secondly, `onclick="open();` should probably be `onclick="open"`. You don't typically set onclick to a called function, you instead just indicate the name of the function to be called when the click happens. More about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick).

So, you might try a line like this instead of your line.

```
<div onclick="open" class="fas fa-bars"></div>
```

or

```
<span onclick="open" class="fas fa-bars"></span>
```

div and span are elements I know you can place click handlers onto.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jquery toggle class instead? e.g.

set the style first, of course you need to set media query with `max-width:780`:

```
 #menu {
   visibility:hidden;     
 }

 #menu.active {
   visibility:visible;
 }
```

and then the jquery:

```
$('#menu').toggleClass("active");
```